# Accept accent marks & ñ on javascript

Tags: javascript, bots, diacritics

I'm making a bot that answers questions given some key words. It's a very easy code developed by Deni Spasovski. However, my website is in Spanish, and I need to be able to use accent marks & ñ as part of the key words. For example:

```
{ "keys": ["cómo", "estás"], "value": 0 }
```

However, despite my efforts, I can't seem to fix the code. I don't know that much about coding. Maybe it's a very easy thing I have to implement to one of the scripts but I really do not know what it is.

I would be more than grateful if you could help me.

Thank you very, very much in advance!!

This is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--Read the source Luke!-->
    <title>Answer bot</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body, html
        {
            height: 100%;
        }
        .wrap
        {
            height: 80%;
            overflow: auto;
            max-height: 80%;
            display: block;
        }
        .content
        {
            height: 100%;
            display: table;
            vertical-align: bottom;
        }
        .subcontent
        {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: bottom;
        }
        .answerbot-input
        {
            color: #1AA1E1;
        }
        .answerbot-ai
        {
            color: #CE5043;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 800px; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div id="wrap" class="wrap">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="subcontent" id='subcontent'>
                    <p class='answerbot-ai'>
                        Don't be afraid, talk to me.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="inputtext" style="width: 100%;" onkeyup="keypressInput(this, event);"><br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="data.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _answerBot = new answerBot();
        function keypressInput(sender, event) {
            if (event.which == 13) {
                document.getElementById('subcontent').innerHTML += _answerBot.processInput(sender.value);
                sender.value = '';
                correctScroll("wrap");
            }
        }

        function correctScroll(elementId) {
            var objDiv = document.getElementById(elementId);
            objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the data.js:

```
if (answerBot) {
    answerBot.prototype.specialContext = {
        "wrongInput": ["I don't understand you.", "Could you rephrase the question?"],
        "emptyInput": ["Please say something", "Speak louder", "Well i can't read minds."],
        "rephrase": ["Can you tell me if your question was about one of the following things:"]
    };

    answerBot.prototype.keywords = [
        { "keys": ["hi"], "value": 0 },
        { "keys": ["hello"], "value": 0 },
        { "keys": ["life", "universe", "everything"], "value": 1 },
        { "keys": ["software", "development"], "value": 2 },
        { "keys": ["software", "engineering"], "value": 2 },
        { "keys": ["who", "made", "you"], "value": 3 },
        { "keys": ["who", "wrote", "you"], "value": 3 },
        { "keys": ["who", "coded", "you"], "value": 3 },
        { "keys": ["is", "this", "real", "life"], "value": 4 },
        { "keys": ["who", "is", "deni"], "value": 5 },
        { "keys": ["tell", "me", "about", "deni"], "value": 5 },
        { "keys": ["tell", "me", "about", "author"], "value": 5 },
        { "keys": ["show", "me", "author"], "value": 5 },
        { "keys": ["can", "see", "source"], "value": 6 },
        { "keys": ["can", "see", "sourcecode"], "value": 6 },
        { "keys": ["show", "me", "code"], "value": 6 },
        { "keys": ["how", "are", "you"], "value": 7 },
        { "keys": ["who", "is", "this"], "value": 8 }];

    answerBot.prototype.answers = [
        {
            "description": "Hi!",
            "values": ["Hello there!", "Hi how can I help you today", "Hi! What brings you here?"]
        },
        {
            "description": "What is the answer to life the universe and everything?",
            "values": ["42"]
        },
        {
            "description": "What is software development?",
            "values": ["Programming! Do you speak it?"]
        },
        {
            "description": "Who created me?",
            "values": ["I was created by another <a href='http://about.me/deni' target='_blank'>bot</a>.", "The question is who sent you here?"]
        },
        {
            "description": "Is this real life?",
            "values": ["No this is the internetz!", "Find out <a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txqiwrbYGrs' target='_blank'>yourself</a>!"]
        },
        {
            "description": "Who is Deni?",
            "values": ["This is his <a href='https://plus.google.com/+DeniSpasovski/' target='_blank'>G+ profile</a>.", "This is his <a href='www.linkedin.com/in/denispasovski' target='_blank'>Linkedin profile</a>."]
        },
        {
            "description": "Where is your source?",
            "values": ["Here is the <a href='https://github.com/denimf/Answer-bot' target='_blank'>source</a>."]
        },
        {
            "description": "How are you?",
            "values": ["I'm good how are you?"]
        },
        {
            "description": "Who is this?",
            "values": ["StackOverflow Exception occurred", "The question is who are you?"]
        }
        ];
}
```

And this is the scripts.js:

```
var answerBot = function () {
    var _this = this;
    _this.processInput = function (text) {
        updateUrl(text);
        var _result = "<p class='answerbot-input'>" + text + "</p>";
        text = text.replace(new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z ]", "g"), " ");
        text = text.replace(new RegExp("[ ]{2,}", "g"), " ");
        var _words = text.toLowerCase().split(" ");
        var _answers = [];
        var _title = "";
        if (_words.length === 0 || _words.toString() === '') { //if the input is empty
            _answers = _this.specialContext.emptyInput;
            _title = _this.specialContext.emptyInput;
        } else {
            var _possibleAnswers = findMatches(_words);
            if (_possibleAnswers.length === 0) { //if no answer found
                _answers = _this.specialContext.wrongInput;
                _title = _this.specialContext.wrongInput;
            }
            if (_possibleAnswers.length == 1) { //context recognized
                _answers = _this.answers[_possibleAnswers[0]].values;
                _title = _this.answers[_possibleAnswers[0]].description;
            }
            if (_possibleAnswers.length > 1) {
                _result += formatText(_this.specialContext.rephrase, _this.specialContext.rephrase);
                for (var i = 0; i < _possibleAnswers.length; i++) {
                    _result += formatText(_this.answers[_possibleAnswers[i]].description, _this.answers[_possibleAnswers[i]].description);
                }
            }
        }
        if (_answers.length > 0) {
            var _rand = Math.floor((Math.random() - 0.001) * _answers.length);
            _result += formatText(_answers[_rand], _title);
        }
        return _result;
    };

    function formatText(text, title) {
        return "<p class=\'answerbot-ai\' title=\'" + title + "\'>" + text + "</p>";
    }

    function findMatches(words) {
        var foundKeywords = [];
        var _possibleAnswers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < _this.keywords.length; i++) {
            foundKeywords[i] = 0;
            for (var j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                if (_this.keywords[i].keys.indexOf(words[j]) >= 0) {
                    foundKeywords[i]++;
                    if (foundKeywords[i] == _this.keywords[i].keys.length) {
                        return [_this.keywords[i].value];
                    }
                }
            }
            if (foundKeywords[i] * 2 > _this.keywords[i].keys.length) {
                _possibleAnswers.push(_this.keywords[i].value);
            }
        }
        return _possibleAnswers.filter(function (elem, pos) {
            return _possibleAnswers.indexOf(elem) == pos;
        });
    }

    function updateUrl(text){
        history.pushState(null, null, "#question=" + encodeURIComponent(text));
        if(typeof ga === "function")//google analytics
            ga('send', 'event', 'question', text);
    }
};
```

Comment: What's the problem? What does/doesn't work?

Comment: Alex, I tested in the browser's console and I don't see any problems with special characters. Try add `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to your HTML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three possible issues:

1) This line:

```
text = text.replace(new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z ]", "g"), " ");
```

will replace anything that isn't in the "normal" alphabet with a space. You might choose to replace it at some point to include characters with diacritics, but to get it working you can simply comment it out.

2) Make sure your files (in particular, data.js) are saved with UTF-8 encoding.

3) Ensure you have an appropriate value in the answers array and then use its index in keywords.value. e.g.

```
    {
        "description": "cómo estás?",
        "values": ["muy bien"]
    }
```